# Autosize ListView Items in WPF Based on Parent Size

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, size

I have a ListView in my project and I want the items in the ListView to responsively resize relative to the parent window size. This automatic size change is like the instagram Windows app:

gif: http://uupload.ir/files/c0rv_insta.gif

I want to be able to specify a MaxHeight and MaxWidth in the DataTemplate such that more items will be displayed when the items reach the size limit.

This is my code:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="ViewPosts" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageUser}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <v:StateViewPostSimple/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and this is my DataTemplate / StateViewPostSimple:

```
<UserControl ....>
   <Grid>
       <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Images[0].URI}" MaxHeight="150" MaxWidth="150" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100"/>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I set *MaxHeight*, *MaxWidth* and *MinHeight*, *MinWidth* but it does not make difference.

Comment: Regarding the choice for `ItemsPanelTemplate`, it seems like `UniformGrid` behaves closer to what you need than `WrapPanel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because a horizontal `WrapPanel` does not stretch its contents, it either fits the item or overflow into the next row.

One solution would be to override measure and arrange methods which takes more effort.

Another is to use `UniformGrid` as `ItemsPanelTemplate` which automatically stretches its contents.

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding NumberOfRows}" Columns="{Binding NumberOfColumns}"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Then modify these two variables (NumberOfRows, NumberOfColumns) in code like:

```
//you need access to listview object
//set the number of columns based on the current width of listview
if(listview.ActualWidth <= 450)
    NumberOfColumns = 3;
else if(listview.ActualWidth <= 600)
    ...
```

or if you can formulate that into:

```
NumberOfColumns = (int)Math.listview.ActualWidth / 150;
if(NumberOfColumns < 3) NumberOfColumns = 3;
```

then you can find the number of rows:

```
//ImageUserList.Count = number of all items
//listview.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().Count() can be used instead
NumberOfRows = (int)Math.Ceiling(ImageUserList.Count / (double)NumberOfColumns);
```

make sure you get `DataContext` right in order to bind to these two variables.